# Socket.io with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to implement `socket.io` with `angular` client. Lets say I am having 3 routes for my application.

> http://localhost:4000/#/abc
>
> http://localhost:4000/#/abd
>
> http://localhost:4000/#/abe

Here I am emitting file processing status from backend to client. I only want to display the status to the users who are all in route 3. What is the best way to achieve this in angular?

**node.js**

```
io.emit('Test', {
        Test: "Test"
});
```

**javascript**

```
socket.on('Test', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on client side your location through the [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) service.

So just do

```
socket.on('Test', function (data) {
    if ( $location.path().indexOf('/abe') != -1)
    {
           // display status
    }
});
```

Comment: It is advisable to use set of codes  inside a controller?

Comment: Depends on you app structure and for what you're using `socket.io`. In your case it seems that you want to display something on a specific page when the user is there so you should put it in the `controller`.